# WLST Detect / Start Weblogic server

Tags: java, weblogic, wlst

I use Weblogic server for my application and am trying to automate data source update task.

So, I have a script (UpdateDataSource.py) which updates the data source to what I need.
Now, I need Weblogic to restart once the data source has been updated. So I am trying something like;

```
call wlst UpdateDataSource.py
call startWebLogic.cmd
```

But my question is after I update the data source through script, I do not want to directly start the weblogic server (I need to close the existing one and then start)
How do I automate the same?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about your question. 
1. If you want to shutdown the WLS, use shutdown command in WLST
2. if you want to start WLS in another window, add "start" before the call command, like:
start call startWebLogic.cmd

Comment: Ok...so my question is, while updating the data source (through the WLST script), my weblogic server needs to be running....once that script is execured, my data source has been updated and I need to restart weblogic server for the changes to take effect...so i need to close the instance which is already running and start weblogic again...

Comment: you mean how to know the WLS running or not? Have you tried："shutdown(serverName, block='true')"?